# Phonegap webintent plugin getting called with content not working

Tags: plugins, cordova, share

I have tried using the plugin, so that an image from a gallary can be "shared" with my phonegap app - but it didn't work.
I have added the plugin using the CLI tool, add the webintent.js file to the www folder and referrenced it properly.
I have changed the androidmanifest.xml and added the intent-filter.

When I try to share an image with my app, the phonegap app starts and only the failure callbacks are called from the webintent js functions (I've tried them all - window.plugins.webintent.onNewIntent, window.plugins.webintent.getExtra, indow.plugins.webintent.getUri..)

Can anyone help please?
Did it work for you?

Doron

Comment: Ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use file phonegap plugin to work.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: why? how is the file plugin relevant?